# Conditional probability in a Pakistani cricket tournament

Tags: probability, probability-theory

As a part of an assignment, I am facing a problem in following question (pretty long one)
In a national-level cricket tournament, 3 teams from 3
different cities Lahore, Islamabad and Karachi participated. Team
Lahore is the defending champion (i.e., they were the winners of
the previous year's tournament). The policies of the tournament
stated that teams of Islamabad and Karachi (other than the
defending champion) would play a match (Round-1) consisting of 2
games. The statistics tell us that Islamabad will beat Karachi with
probability 0.7. If none of the teams win both the matches in
Round-1, then Lahore would be declared as the winners again. If
any of the team wins both the matches in Round-1 than it would
compete with team Lahore in another match (Round-2) of 2 games
and would have to defeat Lahore in both the games to win the title
of championship. If Lahore wins the 1st game of Round-2, the 2nd game would not be played and
the tournament would conclude. We also know that Lahore will win from Islamabad with
probability 0.5 and from Karachi with probability 0.6. Now, considering that all the matches are
independent and end with a win/lose result (i.e., no match is a draw):
**a. Find the probability that Round-2 will be required

b. Find the probability that Islamabad will win Round-1

c. What is the probability that Lahore will remain the champions for this year as well

d. Given that Round-2 is played, what is the conditional probability that:

i. Islamabad survives the Round-1

ii. Lahore remains the champion

e. Given that Round-2 is played with just one game, find the probability that Islamabad was
the winner of Round-1**
I have been been able to solve (I think) parts a, b, c and i of part d but I have no clue on how to attempt ii part of d and part e. I am posting my solution in the question because I think they are all related and I also think that If I did earlier parts correctly, remaining parts would have been done without trouble. Let me post my solution without further discussion.
**Proposed Solution:**
Let's first define the required events
Ii = {Islamabad wins from Karachi in ith game}  P(Ii) = 0.7
Ki = {Karachi wins from Islamabad in ith game}  P(Ki) = P(Iic) = 0.3
Li = {Lahore wins from Islamabad} P(Li) = 0.5   P(Lic) = 0.5
Lk = {Lahore wins from Karachi} P(Lk) = 0.6 P(Lkc) = 0.4
R2 = {Round 2 is required or played}        P(R2) = ?
IR1 = {Islamabad wins/survives round 1} P(IR1) = ?
KR1 = {Karachi wins/survives round 1}   P(KR1) = ?
Lc = {Lahore remains the champion this year}    P(Lc) = ?
O = {Round 2 is played with just one game}
P(IR1| R2) = ?
P(Lc | R2) = ?
P(IR1| O) = ?
**a) Find the probability that Round 2 is required? P(R2) = ?**
We know that round 2 is only required when either Islamabad wins both matches or Karachi wins both matches. We can write this as following
P(R2) = P(I1). P(I2) + P(K1). P(K2)
= (0.7) (0.7) + (0.3) (0.3)
P(R2)   =  0.49 + .09 = 0.58
**b) Find the probability that Islamabad wins Round 1? P(IR1) = ?**
We know that Islamabad wins/survives round 1 if and only if it wins both matches from Karachi and its probability can be modeled as
P(IR1) = P(I1). P(I2)
P(IR1) = (0.7). (0.7) = 0.49
**c) What is the probability that Lahore remain the champions of this year as well? P(Lc) = ?**
Lahore can remain the champion if round 2 is not played OR Islamabad wins Round1 and loses from Lahore in first match OR Islamabad wins Round 1 and wins from Lahore in first game and loses from Lahore in second game OR Karachi wins Round 1 and loses from Lahore in game 1 OR Karachi wins Round 1 and wins from Lahore in 1st game and loses from Lahore in 2nd game. This statement can be modeled in the form of following equation
P(Lc) = P(R2c) + P(IR1). P(Li) + P(IR1). P(Lic). P(Li) + P(KR1). P(Lk) + P(KR1). P(Lkc). P(Lk)
=   (0.42) + (0.49). (0.5) + (0.49). (0.5). (0.5) + (0.09).(0.6) + (0.09). (0.4) . (0.6)
=  0.42 + 0.245 + 0.1225 + 0.054 + 0.0216
P(Lc) =  0.8631
**d) Given that the Round 2 is played, what is the conditional probability that

i- Islamabad survives the Round 1   P(IR1| R2) = ?

ii - Lahore Remains the Champion  P(Lc| R2) = ?**
i)
We know that by Baye's rule we can write
P(IR1| R2) = P(R2 | IR1) . P(IR1) / P(R2)
We also know that if Islamabad wins round 1, round 2 has to be played i.e
P(R2| R1) = 1, So
P(IR1| R¬2) = (1) . (0.49) / 0.58 = 0.8448
ii)
P(Lc| R2) = P(R2| Lc) P(Lc) / P(R2)
**In the above equation, we have P(Lc) = 0.8631 and P(R2) = 0.58 but we don't know the value of P(R2| Lc) and  I have no idea how to approach this problem**
e) Given that Round 2 is played with just one game, find the probability that Islamabad was the winner of Round 1? P(IR1 | O) = ?
P(IR1| O) = P(O | IR1) P(IR1) / P(O)
**I have no idea how to approach this problem either.**
Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's tidy up all the words…

- Islamabad beats Karachi with probability 0.7
- Lahore beats Islamabad with probability 0.5
- Lahore beats Karachi with probability 0.6
- In round 1, if neither Islamabad nor Karachi win both games, Lahore remains champion
- In round 2, the winner of round 1 must win *both* games to become champion, else Lahore remains champion (the tournament stops early if Lahore wins the first game)

…and construct a probability fen (tree) out of it.

```
      (L)
       ^
    2*.7*.3     /-.4*.4-> (K)
       |        |
----R1-+-.3*.3->+--else-> (L)
       |   K    R2
       \-.7*.7->+-.5*.5-> (I)
           I    |
                \--else-> (L)
```

Each + represents a branching point, with I, K and L standing for Islamabad, Karachi and Lahore respectively. Letters in brackets denote winners and expressions on each arrow denote the probability of that arrow being followed from the branch point it starts from.

The solutions for parts (a), (b), (c) and (d)(i) are correct. Here are the solutions for the remaining parts.

> (d)(ii) *If round 2 is played, what is the probability that Lahore remains champion?*

There are exactly two ways Lahore can remain champion if the tournament proceeds to round 2:

- If Islamabad progresses (0.49) but doesn't win the two games required ($1-0.5^2=0.75$)
- If Karachi progresses (0.09) but doesn't win the two games required ($1-0.4^2=0.84$)

Hence the answer to this part is $0.49\times0.75+0.09\times0.84=0.4431$.

> (e) *If round 2 is played, but only for one game, what is the probability that Islamabad won round 1?*

Again, there are exactly two ways for this to happen:

- Islamabad wins round 1 (0.49), then loses the next game (0.5)
- Karachi wins round 1 (0.09), then loses the next game (0.6)

From the start of round 1, the probability of the first case happening is $0.49\times0.5=0.245$, while that of the second is $0.09\times0.6=0.054$. Now think of these probabilities as shares in a reduced event space where round 2 is played for only one game; the share of the first case, where Islamabad wins, is $\frac{0.245}{0.245+0.054}=0.8194$ (to 4 decimal places) of the total. This is the answer to part (e).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Parchey Taxel. it makes perfect sense. Can we somehow model the above equations in form of Baye's rule. I am basically confused where to use Baye's rule, LOTP and Tree structure?

Comment: Some people use trees to visualise branching probabilities, and I favour them quite a lot (really, it's up to personal preference). The law of total probability (which I used) can naturally be seen in such a tree, and is therefore suited for events that happen in sequence (like the cricket tournament here). The Bayes/Price theorem is better suited for events that can happen in parallel, like rates of cancer in people over 65.

Comment: Thanks man! can yo have a look at following question of mine http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929285/a-troublesome-counting-problem