# A troublesome Counting Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have the following question that I fail to comprehend
Mallory is planning to go to Russia in 2018 to see the FIFA World Cup.
Out of the total 64 matches that are being held in the World Cup, she
decides to choose from the first 20 in the first week (she will be in
Russia for only a week), none of which are scheduled at the same
time. There are 4 matches to choose from for each day of the week,
Monday through Friday. Mallory decides to buy tickets for 7 randomly
selected matches out of the 20, with all choices equally likely. What is
the probability that she will have one or more matches to attend every
single day between Monday and Friday?
**My Attempt to solution**
As we know there are `20 choose 7` total ways of picking 7 tickets from 20 available tickets. We also know that there are 4 ways of picking a ticket for each day from Monday to Friday and there are `15 choose 2` ways of picking remaining 2 tickets from remaining 15 tickets. So all this can be represented as

```
4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 105  //(105 is 15 choose 2)
```

But when we multiply all of them, it becomes 107520 which exceeds the total number of ways 7 tickets can be chosen from 20 i.e `20 choose 7` = 77520. How is this possible? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the schedule where Mallory attends the matches $1$ and $2$ on both Monday and Tuesday, and match $1$ every other day.
Your count includes this schedule as follows:
match $1$ on Monday through Friday is one of the $4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4$
ways to choose one match each day, and
match $2$ on Monday and Tuesday is one of the $\binom{15}{2}$ ways
to choose the remaining two tickets.

But look: match $2$ on Monday and Tuesday, match $1$ the other three days
is a different choice among the $4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4$ choices for one match each day, and match $1$ on Monday and Tuesday is one of the $\binom{15}{2}$ choices for the remaining tickets. But it is the exact same schedule as the one in the previous paragraph!

In short, you have allowed Mallory to choose the same schedule in several
different ways, and you have counted each of these as a different schedule.

---

Some hints about a  *correct* way to count the number of ways Mallory can buy tickets are in the comment by Ross Millikan.

Comment: So should it be 4.4.4.4.4 for one match each day and 3.3 for match 2 on Monday and Tuesday (or any two days)?

Comment: No, the point is it is a bad idea to start by picking just one match each day and then try to fill in the remaining two matches. In fact the correct answer is not divisible by $4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4$ so you're practically guaranteed to get a wrong answer that way.

Comment: There are only two patterns that satisfy a match each day.  She can see three matches on one day and one each other day, or two matches on two days and one each other day.  You should separately compute the number of choices for each pattern.  Pick the days that will have one number of matches, then pick the matches each day.

Comment: and should it be `4 choose 3` .4 .4.4.4 for 3 matches in one day and 1 match for all other days plus `4 choose 2` . `4 choose 2`. 4 .4 .4 for 2 matches on any two days and 1 match in remaining three days?

Comment: To wit, the correct probability is 352/969 or around 36%, right?

Comment: I think, I need a bit more clue on how to solve it

Comment: I think, I got it. There are 5 ways of choosing a days with 3 matches so `4 choose 3` .4.4.4.4.5 is complete first term. Similarly, there are `5 choose 2` ways of choosing 2 days with two matches so second complete term will be 10.6.6.4.4.4. After adding these both terms we get 28160 ways of having one or more matches in one day and required probability is 28160/77520 which is about 36%

Comment: That looks right to me.